# Delete all blocks except specified ones in simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there any equivalent command to the [clearvars -except keepVariables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) which can be used in a simulink model to delete all blocks, ports and lines, except specified ones?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can maybe create your own version using a combination of `find_system`, `delete_block`, `delete_line` and/or `Simulink.BlockDiagram.deleteContents` & `Simulink.SubSystem.deleteContents`.

Comment: See also [Simulink Manipulation Utilities](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42534-simulink-manipulation-utilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **one** general way to do it, explained used the in-built example `vdp`:

```
simulink;
name = 'vdp';

%// open system, pause just for displaying purposes
open_system(name);
% pause(3)

%// find system, specify blocks to keep
allblocks = find_system(name);
ToKeep = {'Out1';'Out2'};
%// add systemname to strings
ToKeep = strcat(repmat({[name  '/']},numel(ToKeep),1), ToKeep);
%// Alternative, directly, so save one line:
ToKeep = {'vdp/Out1';'vdp/Out2'};

%// create mask
ToDelete = setdiff(allblocks,ToKeep);
%// filter out main system
ToDelete = setxor(ToDelete,name);

%// try-catch inside loop as in this example not everything is deletable
for ii = 1:numel(ToDelete)
    try
        delete_block(ToDelete{ii})
    catch 
        disp('Some objects couldn''t be deleted')
    end
end
```

If all objects are deletable you may use

```
cellfun(@(x) delete_block(x),ToDelete)
```

instead of the loop.

---

Regarding your comment:
Imagine you just want to keep all `Scope` and `Out` blocks. You need to find there names also by `find_system` and gather them to a list:

```
%// what to keep
scopes = find_system(name,'BlockType','Scope')
outs = find_system(name,'BlockType','Outport')
%// gather blocks to keep
ToKeep = [scopes; outs];

%// create mask
ToDelete = setdiff(allblocks,ToKeep);
%// filter out main system
ToDelete = setxor(ToDelete,name);
```

Comment: Seems to be almost what i am looking for. But the problem is that i have a very large system, so if I have to specify every single name, the list will be too long. Is there a way to make the `ToKeep` list being `names` **(Main/Sub1/Sub2/Sub3)** and/or `blocks types` **(input ports, multiplexers)**