# Add inports & outports to Simulink C Mex S-Function mask

Tags: matlab, simulink, mex, s-function

I am trying to amend the example given [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-dynamic-masked-subsystems.html) for creating a dynamic masked subsystem, where I want to dynamically change the number of imports and outports to an S-Function.

I have a very simple S-Function implemented in C (it's the [timestwo](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/example-of-a-basic-c-mex-s-function.html) example in the documentation) and for which I wish the user to be able to define the number of inputs and number of outputs in a mask.  The intention is then, within the S Function, to manipulate the received input values and write to the output values.  The S-Function will eventually do some quite complicated stuff and I need multiple instances of it in Simulink, hence why I want it defined in a library.

I have put the S-Function into a library and unlocked it by choosing `Diagram->Unlock Library`.

I have defined 2 variables, `numInports` and `numOutports` in the `Parameters & Dialog` pane of the mask editing window.

I then add the following to the `Initialization` pane:

```
blocks = find_system(gcb,...
          'LookUnderMasks','on',...
          'FollowLinks','on',...
          'RegExp', 'on',...
          'BlockType', 'port');

if ~isempty(blocks)
   Simulink.SubSystem.deleteContents(gcb);
end

for n=0:(numInports - 1)
    label = sprintf('/In%d', n);
    add_block('built-in/Inport',[gcb,label]);
end

for n=0:(numOutports - 1)
    label = sprintf('/Out%d', n);
    add_block('built-in/Outport',[gcb,label]);
end
```

The intention is for the initialisation to delete all imports and outports when the parameters are changed, then recreate them.  I then save the model within the library.

The find_system() command should find and delete all blocks with port in the type, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083282/delete-all-blocks-except-specified-ones-in-simulink-model) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html#zmw57dd0e175672).

I have created a model that uses this library model S Function implementation.  However, when I update the parameters, I get the error:

```
Error in 'MyModel/MyLibrarySFunction': Initialization commands cannot be evaluated. Caused by:
    A new block named 'MyModel/MyLibrarySFunction/In0' cannot be added.
```

Can anybody please advise what is going wrong here?

EDIT:

The [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html) for `find_system()` has `all` as a valid parameter value, not the `on` I used and which was in the documentation example, but this seems to have no effect when I change it.  I added:

```
msg = sprintf('Num blocks: %d', numel(blocks));
disp(msg);
```

just after the `find_system()` call and get 0 for the number of blocks found, so I guess the problem may be that In0 is not deleted and hence I am trying to reinsert it.

Comment: Is there anything other than the S-Function block and inport and outport blocks in the subsystem?  If not, then why not just mask the S-Function block and eliminate the need to deal with adding/deleting the inport/outport blocks.

Comment: Thanks @PhilGoddard - no there's nothing else in the system.  How do I mask the S-Function block?  I thought that was what I was doing when editing the `Initialization` tab in the S-Function mask dialog.

Comment: John, there may be some confusion about the terminology you are using. When you want an s-function to have number of ports based on mask values you do it from inside the s-function using ssSetNumInputPorts or its output version. You should not need to add port blocks using mask code. Check out other s-function examples to understand how to use mask parameters and control s-function behavior.

Comment: John, your description indicates that you are not masking the S-Function block directly, but rather putting the S-Function in a subsystem (along with inports and outports) and then masking that subsystem.  What you should be doing is masking the S-Function, passing the (user specified) required number of ports into the S-Function through its parameter list, and then (as @Navan indicates) using the ssSetNumInputPorts and ssSetNumOutputPorts macros to define the number of inputs and outputs that the S-Function requires.